# Good introduction to the Berkeley db C api installed on OS X?

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I'm looking for a good introduction to the Berkeley db api that is installed on OS X. I have looked at this Oracle document: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg/C/BerkeleyDB-Core-C-GSG.pdf

Which seems to be a newer version. I am not able to compile this and get the following error:

```
test.c:23: error: ‘DB_CREATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:23: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:23: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:26: error: ‘DB’ has no member named ‘open’
test.c:42: error: too many arguments to function ‘dbp->close’
```

AFAIK, the version installed on OS X is the old BSD licensed 1.85.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB 1.85 is only there to support some system configuration files such as `/etc/pwd.db`, so it shouldn't really be used.

That being said, it *is* much simpler than the newer Berkeley DB releases. [`dbopen(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/dbopen/) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search on Apple's support site. It looks like there are probably more recent releases of Berkeley DB installed on Mac OS X. I found that Berkeley DB 4.2 is installed on Mac OS X Server v10.5 and used in the Open Directory Server.